# Java adding objects according to ratios and population sizes

Tags: java, arrays, loops, if-statement, simulation

My project is a simple agent based simulation that models the spread of disease. The simulation consists of agents and map, the classes that belong to agents are: `Civil`, `Medic` and `Animal`. Currently I'm trying to fill the map according to the size of populations: `noMedics`, `noCivils`, `noAnimals` and amount of `healthy`, `ill`, and `immune` agents that should add up to total population of both humans and animals.
The way that health status of an agent is determined is simple - `random.nextInt(3)`, `0` being healthy, `1` ill and `2` immune.  The way that I would usually fill the map with one of the agent class is as follows:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < noAnimals; i++) {
    IAgent animal = new Animal(map, rnd.nextInt(3), 2, 3);
    agentList.add(animal);
}
```

However the issue arises whenever I would try to implement the remaining parameters of simulation that is: `noHealthy`, `noImmune`, `noIll`. I can't seem to find a loop or condition that would fullfill my need which is to **"fairly"** fill the map with all agents of in the given createAgents() method. Create agents takes 6 parameters:  `noHealthy`, `noImmune`, `noIll`, `noAnimals`, `noCivil`, `noMedics`.
I've tried few things already but the one that compiles and runs correctly so far is as follows: I'm creating a loop that runs from `currNoImmune` until `noImmune` from parameters and whenever a condition `sumForImmune < halfNoAnimals && currNoImmune <= noImmune` is fulfilled it adds an animal to the simulation and increments `sumForImmune` and `currNoImmune` once. The reverse check is done for civlians `sumForImmune >= halfNoAnimals && currNoImmune <= noImmune` incrementing the same variables and adding a civil to the simulation. Here is the code for method I've described:

```java
while (sumForImmune <= noImmune) {
    if (sumForImmune < halfNoAnimals && currNoImmune <= noImmune) {
        agentList.add(new Animal(map, 2, 0, 2));
        sumForImmune++;
        currNoImmune++;
    }
    if (sumForImmune >= halfNoAnimals && currNoImmune <= noImmune) {
        agentList.add(new Civil(map, 2, 0, 2));
        sumForImmune++;
        currNoImmune++;
    }
}
```

Then there are two loops that run until `noIll` and `noHealthy` and that's how agents are created so far. It works however not quite how I hoped it would. Numbers that are passed as arugments to `createAgents()` aren't being reflected on the map for all possible inputs. I realize that this task is beyond my capabilities since I've spend a good amount of time trying to figure it out, despite that I would still love to understand how it's done and how it can be achieved.

What I mean by **fairly** is as close to **50:50** as possible - whenever user inputs an uneven number of 3 immune, 1 animal and 2 civil agents there should be 2 immune civilians and 1 immune animal. Same logic shoud be extended to the missing parameters that is healthy and ill agents.

**Edit:**
What I mean by that mess written above is that I need an algorithm to place agents according to the ratios determined by noHealthy:noIll:noImmune for both population of Civilians (noCivils) and population of Animals (noAnimals). Taking into account that Medics are already immune so noImmune should shrink by the number of Medics present in the simulation.

**Edit2:**
I've played around with the maths a bit and this is what I managed to get but there is still issue with 1:1:1 ratios as they don't give expected results for given population sizes. One more thing is this doesn't account for medics yet, just so it doesn't mess the ratios and makes the logic a bit easier.

```java
void createAgents(int noAnimals, int noCivil, noIll, noImmune, noHealthy) {
    double sumTheRatio = noHealthy + noIll + noImmune;

    double animalsPart = noAnimals / sumTheRatio;
    double numHealthyAnimals = noHealthy * animalsPart;
    double numIllAnimals = noIll * animalsPart;
    double numImmuneAnimals = noImmune * animalsPart;

    double civilPart = noCivil / sumTheRatio;
    double numHealthyCivil = noHealthy * civilPart;
    double numIllCivil = noIll * civilPart;
    double numImmuneCivil = noImmune * civilPart;

//The only issue is when ratios of agent health states are 1:1:1
//- for example for ratios like 18:18:18 and 26 civilians 28 animals will
// give 27 agents for both animals and civilians (+/- 1 from expected numbers)
//- another example 7:7:7 and 1 civil and 20 animals will give 0 agents
// for civilians and 21 agents for animals (+/- 1 from expected numbers)
//- another example 14:14:14 and 38 civilians and 4 animals will give 39
// agents for civilians and 3 agents for animals (+/- 1 from expected numbers)

    System.out.println("Rounded ratio number for animals:"
            + "\n healthy - " + Math.round(numHealthyAnimals)
            + " ill - " + Math.round(numIllAnimals)
            + " immune - " + Math.round(numImmuneAnimals));
    System.out.println("Rounded ratio number for civilians:"
            + "\n healthy - " + Math.round(numHealthyCivil)
            + " ill - " + Math.round(numIllCivil)
            + " immune - " + Math.round(numImmuneCivil));
}
```

Then simply iterating to: `Math.round(numHealthyCivil)`, `Math.round(numIllCivil)`, `Math.round(numImmuneCivil)` and adding respective agent with each iteration.
Is there a way to adjust this algorithm or perhaps there is a need for different function responsible for agents creation whenever ratios are 1:1:1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say that Medics should have an Immune health status. The remaining problem is therefore to assign Civilians and Animals a health status of Healthy, Ill, or Immune such that:

```
noCivils + noAnimals + noMedics = noHealthy + noIll + noImmune
```

One way of doing this would be to create a health status array `noCivils + noAnimals` long and populate it with `noHealthy`, `noIll`, and `noImmune-noMedics` elements of the corresponding type `(0, 1, 2`). You then randomly shuffle this array and use the values to assign a health status to Civilians and Animals in turn.

Here's some Java code to illustrate:

```
static void createAgents(int noHealthy, int noImmune, int noIll, 
                         int noAnimals, int noCivil, int noMedics)
{
    for (int i=0; i<noMedics; i++) {
        // create and add Medic, with health status Immune
    }
    
    int remImmune = noImmune - noMedics;
    
    assert noCivil + noAnimals == noHealthy + noIll + remImmune;
    
    int caAgents = noCivil + noAnimals;
    
    Integer[] agentStatus = new Integer[caAgents];
    Arrays.fill(agentStatus, 0, noHealthy, 0);
    Arrays.fill(agentStatus, noHealthy, noHealthy+noIll, 1);
    Arrays.fill(agentStatus, noHealthy+noIll, noHealthy+noIll+remImmune, 2);

    Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(agentStatus));

    int j = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<noAnimals; i++, j++) {
        // create and add Animal, with health status status[j]
    }
    for (int i=0; i<noCivil; i++, j++) {
        // create and add Civilian, with health status status[j]
    }   
}
```

Comment: That does indeed work, I was actually thinking of calculating ratios of three numbers (health statuses) for each noAnimals and noCivil but this way it's more transparent. Thanks for this great instruction.